# Open excel file in Client machine after saved on hive.

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, excel-interop

I want to write **DataTable** on excel sheet and open in client machine. Let client to save the file on his preferred location. I have created the file and saved on hive. but couldn't open it on client machine. I'm using **interop.dll** for excel.

```
excelWorkBook.Saved = true;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    excelWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(filename);
});

excelWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
excelWorkBook = null;
excelApp.Quit();
```

I want to either open the saved excel sheet on client machine and delete the file from hive after client save it on his location.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will open a save file dialog. So user can save the file where ever he wanted..

```
try
        {
            string XlsPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Resources/test.xls");// give ur file path here (where it is stored, in ur case ur Hive path)
            FileInfo fileDet = new System.IO.FileInfo(XlsPath);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Server.UrlEncode(fileDet.Name));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileDet.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.WriteFile(fileDet.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          throw ex; 
        }
```

This is how it be done with SharePoint Web Part

```
try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                SPWeb currentWeb = site.RootWeb;
                currentWeb.ParserEnabled = false;
                SPFile spFile = currentWeb.GetFile(@"/Shared%20Documents/test.xls"); // ur documet url saved in document library
                string localFileName = Path.Combine(@"c:\Users\anbuj\Documents\Backup", string.Format("{0}.xls","tempfile")); // tenpFilePath is where u wanna save ur file
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    FileStream outStream = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Create);
                    byte[] fileData = spFile.OpenBinary();
                    outStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                    outStream.Close();
                }
                    );

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```